# Eclipse updgrade 32 bit to 64 bit windows 7

Tags: java, android, eclipse, windows

I am running 32 bit windows with 32 bit **Eclipse Luna** and 32 bit **Java 7** for android development. No issue. Now I am planning to upgrade **RAM** and install 64 bit **Windows 7**. So my question is if I upgrade my **Windows 7 from 32 to 64 bit**, keeping all program files(which are in C drive) and then download and install 64 bit **Eclipse Mars** with **Java 7/8 64 bit**, will my workspace open and work as like now? Or I have to format C drive, install **64 bit Windows 7** and freshly install **Android SDK** etc ? My workspace is in D drive.

Comment: Eclipse is now deprecated, switch to [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)!

Comment: Correction: Eclipse is deprecated for Android development ... but not in general.

Comment: I prefer eclipse, I am familiar with It. I tried Android studio, but it seems to me complex usage

Comment: Nice, but... do you have a **64 bit CPU**? Anyway, this question is **totally off-topic**, in that it's about switching OS and IDE to 64 bit, not about a **specific programming issue**.

Comment: Yes, i checked my laptop is capable to handle 64 bit OS. It is available in control panel.

Comment: @DerGol...lum: What's with all the bold?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Just **to emphatize** the **meaningful** words.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch to 64 bit. you need to download eclipse and JAVA for 64 bit. And you can link your existing SDK to the new eclipse in windows tab. as I did the same thing in my PC it's working fine for me

**Linking Android SDK to eclipse**

in **Eclipse**--> **Window** --> **Preferences** --> Click On **Android** --> Browse your **SDK location**--> Click **Ok**.

Comment: how to link android SDK ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to instal JRE in to Program Files for 64 bit, other JRE in to Program Files(x86) for 32 bit.
And then to change the JRE in : Windows > Preference > Java > Installed JRS's > edit or add.